# SharePoint Client side web part, newly added web part does not show in web part list

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I have created a webpart using SPfx, Called "Hello world"

Deployed on sharepoint online.
Added as an app. and droped on page.

after that I created another webpart called "Test Webpart" in same solution folder. and deployed it.

but this time, "Test webpart" not showing up.

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase your solution version(package-solution.json) number so you could upgrade it, this'll add new feature to your target site.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awsome, Thanks very much.

Comment: You could accept it as answer so it may help others.